# googlemock EXPECT_CALL with small behaviour variations

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

With the help of googlemock and googletest, I set up a test that checks that different mocked errors are correctly handled by the method under test. Basically my code looks like this:

```
  // setup mock object, and object under test

  // setup initial EXPECT_CALL expectations

  // this expected method call in the middle mocks a failure 
  EXPECT_CALL(*mock, method(arg_in)).
    Times(1).
    WillOnce(Throw(exception_of_type_A));

  // setup cleanup EXPECT_CALL expectations

  // Now invoke method in object under test.
  // Expect exception has been translated to different type.
  EXPECT_THROW(x.method_under_test(), exception_type_B);

  // destructor of mock object will check the mock method invocations
```

Now my mocked method that fails here can not only fail by throwing an exception of type A, but also by throwing an exception of type B, or by returning an unexpected return value.

I can implement this easily enough by copying and pasting the complete TEST() and just changing what the misbehaving mocked method1 will do. But this will make the code messy. Even if I document that these 3 tests are exactly the same except for how the mocked method1 fails in the WillOnce() action specification, a human reader would still have to compare carefully if this is still true.

What would be the correct way in googletest/googlemock to share the common code between the three TESTS and just have them differ in the WillOnce() action?

To my mind comes: Macros, loops over a container with WillOnce() actions, googletest fixtures, static helper methods for setup and cleanup.

I am still new to googletest and not sure how to address this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I implement the test logic in a templated static function that accepts an action as a parameter:

```
template <typename A>
static void paramererizeable_test(A failingAction) {
  // set everything up
  EXPECT_CALL(*mock, method(arg_in)).
    Times(1).
    WillOnce(failingAction);
  // set up more expectations
  // trigger the calls
}

TEST(Section, Method) {
  paramererizeable_test(Throw(exception_of_type_A));
  paramererizeable_test(Throw(exception_of_type_B));
  paramererizeable_test(Return(unexpected_return_value));
}
```

Not sure if this is how it should be done, or if there is a better way, but it works and is readable.